# Power PC to X86 Conversion

Tags: gcc, x86, cross-platform, powerpc

I am working on converting a Power PC based software ,written in C++ and built using Gcc compilers , to a Windows(x86) based platform. At present. As Makefiles are being used to build the software in PPC environment, I am using the Makefile to create a similar solution in Visual Studio by adding the code files manually and Project settings accordingly.

Will this approach make my application work in Windows platform, If not, Is there any better approach to follow.

Comment: You can run gcc on windows, so you can re-use those makefiles

Comment: Wouldn't processor architecture difference cause trouble as the code is written for PPC which differs from X86's endianness and difference in Instruction SEt (RISC ans CISC).

Comment: of course you must fix it because not all codes are portable. It's better to write portable code so that you have less work when switching platforms. What I mean is just that you can use the old makefiles and fix where needed instead of change to VS and have lots of work to do